# What is the value of x?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I tried solving it but I just don't get the answer, does anybody know what the answer is or how to solve it?

Comment: These are similar triangles. The ratios of corresponding sides are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two congruent angles show that the triangles are similar, by the AA Similarity Postulate. Therefore, since similar triangles have proportional sides, $\frac{12}{8}=\frac{x}{10}$, so $x=15$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know the answer.

By similar triangles,
$$\dfrac{12}{8}=\dfrac{x}{10}\\
\implies x=15$$
Just as a side note, this implies, by the converse of Pythagoras' theorem, that the triangles are right angled triangles.

Comment: @user145589 Sure!